# cap deploy:migrations fails with Could not locate Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, gemfile

I'm working on my first rails deployment and having a problem I can't figure out.
mac osx 10.8.2
ruby 1.8.7
Rails 3.2.6
rvm 1.17.2

I've been following this tutorial http://brandnewrails.wordpress.com/ and got stuck on 7c.
I set it all up in RVM, got git running on the server, ran `bundle install` in the app, and wrote the Capistrano recipe in my_app/config/deploy.rb

Then I ran:

`$ capify .` no problem

`$ cap deploy:setup` no errors

`$ cap deploy:check` returned `You appear to have all necessary dependencies installed`

`$ cap deploy:migrations` is where the problem happens. After successfully running a bunch of the commands, capistrano fails. See below:

```
2012-12-10 00:43:56 executing `bundle_install'
* executing "cd /home/{servername}/party/releases/20121209134354 && bundle install --path vendor/bundle"
servers: ["{servername}"]
[{servername}] executing command
** [out :: {servername}] Could not locate Gemfile
command finished in 694ms

failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/alexchee/party/releases/20121209134354 && bundle install --path vendor/bundle'" on {servername}
```

Does anyone know what to do? When I check the app directory, the Gemfile is there. Any ideas or further questions?

Comment: Check what's in the `/home/alexchee/party/releases/20121209134354` folder. It appears the app repository is not getting copied over there for some reason. Are you using the `deploy.rb` file as it is in the blogpost? Or have you commented out some of it?

Comment: Also make sure the gem files (Gemfile and Gemfile.lock) are both checked into your GIT repository.

Comment: ./  ../  Gemfile.lock  .git/  log@  public/  REVISION  tmp/  vendor/

Comment: @PrakashMurthy You're right the whole app wasn't copying over because I hadn't run `git init` etc in my app on my computer. Operator error :/ Thanks for your help! and to you too @Jamsi

Comment: @cheekipoo Awesome. Do update the question with the finding, or add it as an answer so that it helps someone else who comes here with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inability of capistrano to locate a Gemfile in this case seems to be a symptom of not having initiated git in the app locally, that is on my own computer.

My hunch is that since Gemfile is the first file in the list above, that is why it created an error first. If the program had continued, it would have probably had other errors as well.

Even if git is running on the server and the app is bundled up correctly, you must also initiate git locally and direct it to the appropriate files on your server in order for the deploy to work.

Great instructions are listed here: http://brandnewrails.wordpress.com/2012/10/14/lesson-7b/