# Capistrano could not locate Gemfile error on application deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, remote-server, gemfile

I'm trying to deploy my Rails application to production server and I decided to deploy it to DigitalOcean using [this guide](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04#overview) + RVM.

To deploy I use following command:

```
cap production deploy
```

However, it fails at some part requiring gemfile. Here's the log of failed deployment:

```
DEBUG[323dfd0e] Command: cd /home/deploy/zwiadowcy/releases/20140628164657 && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --binstubs /home/deploy/zwiadowcy/shared/bin --path
/home/deploy/zwiadowcy/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
DEBUG[323dfd0e]     Could not locate Gemfile
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host my_ip_address: bundle exit status: 10
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: Nothing written
```

My gemfile already contains all required things:

```
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1.2'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.1'
gem 'capistrano-rvm', github: "capistrano/rvm"
```

I've googled half of the Internet and tried many things, looked through many questions here and I'm now at the point that I don't really know what to do so I kindly ask you for help. Thanks!

Comment: Is your Gemfile definitely checked in?

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: check if Gemfile is being tracked in your repository? Or see: `.gitignore` file in project's root directory, if you've mistakenly put Gemfile there?

Comment: Yes, the Gemfile is being tracked.

Comment: Did you check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788286/cap-deploymigrations-fails-with-could-not-locate-gemfile

Comment: That seems to be a good direction, Icicle. Structure of my git repository is: root and some stuff/actual_rails_app

Comment: Did you initialize git in your local application by running git init .

Comment: Yes, I did initialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify that `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` are checked in Git. For example you could run:

```
git log Gemfile
git log Gemfile.lock
```

You can also verify that those files are present in `/home/deploy/zwiadowcy/releases/20140628164657` on the server.

Running manually the command in the server also helps:

```
cd /home/deploy/zwiadowcy/releases/20140628164657 && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --binstubs /home/deploy/zwiadowcy/shared/bin --path /home/deploy/zwiadowcy/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment
```